# split the result of getJSON in tow parts and use each part to display different DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

say I have the following js:

```
$.getJSON( "http://server/api/", function( data ) 
 {
   $.each(data, function(index, item)
   {
     $("#myid").append('<div class="class1">some html</div>')
   });
});
```

I want to split the result of the json, then I can append to $("#myid") to display `<div clase="clase1">some html</div>` `<div class="class2">some html</div>` simultaneously 
I tried `data.length / 2`this will divide the result but I could not use the other half of the result

**EDIT**
let's say I have the following json result:

```
[{"id": 50, "name": "a"},{"id": 51, "name": "b"}{"id": 52, "name": "c"},{"id": 53, "name": "d"} ...]
```

then I want to generate:

```
<div class="1">a</div>
<div class="2">b</div>
<div class="1">c</div>
<div class="2">d</div>
...
```

Comment: What does your returned data look like?  Also it's `class` not "clase". :)

Comment: This question is unclear. What does the data look like, and what way do you want to split it?

Comment: Are you looking for `String.prototype.slice()` by any chance?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: @JonSG thanks for the link, I will try it, also I updated my question to understand my example